# EditText - setText() Method Not Working - StackOverFlow Exception

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm having issues tying to figure why I'm getting a StackOverFlow Exception on this line of code:

```
 mPassword.setText(phone);
```

I am trying to format a number while the user is typing it in and taking the formatted number and setting it to the EditText widget.  How can I get around or fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onTextChanged() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (s.length() != 0) {
            switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.etUsername: {

            }
            break;

            case R.id.etPassword: {
                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
                mPassword.setText(phone);  //THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            }
            }
        }
    }             

public String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In formatPhoneNumber() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final StringBuffer sbPhone = new StringBuffer(phoneNumber);

    if (sbPhone.length() == 9) {
        //phoneNumber.substring(8, '-');
        //phoneNumber.insert(8, '-');
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("-") == -1) {
            sbPhone.insert(8, "-");
        }
    }
    else if (sbPhone.length() == 8) {
        //phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("-") != -1) {
            sbPhone.delete(sbPhone.indexOf("-"), sbPhone.indexOf("-"));
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is the error:

```
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:81)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:81)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.MeasuredText.setPara(MeasuredText.java:117)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:264)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:324)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:174)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:7106)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6955)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7551)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4410)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-17 09:16:42.844: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):    at android.widget.Text
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you set the TextWatcher on mPassword ?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to handle a huge amount of bytes in a String buffer. You need to check your text watcher to see if there is a logical mistake, or repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are infinitely calling the `onTextChanged` method, since you are setting the text inside the `TextWatcher` which causes the `onTextChanged` to be called again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the approach you are using, cause every time you call:

```
mPassword.setText(phone);
```

This will fire `onTextChanged` handler, which will execute as per code again: `mPassword.setText(phone);`

ending in a StackOverflow.

**EDIT:** One quick fix could be adding a boolean flag for using as a base case in the recursion:

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onTextChanged() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (s.length() != 0) {
            switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.etUsername: {

            }
            break;

            case R.id.etPassword: {
                if (flag){
                  flag = false;
                  return;
                }

                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
                flag = true;  //number formatted!!!
                mPassword.setText(phone);  //THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onTextChanged` method is being called recursively by calling `setText` in it. The `setText` method call causes another trigger of `onTextChanged` which causes `setText` to be called and so on.
Try to set a flag when you edited the TextField from code, so it does not trigger another change. For example:

```
private boolean autochange = false;

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(autochange) { // skip execution if triggered by code
       autochange=false; // next change is not triggered by code
       return;
    }
    if (s.length() != 0) {
        switch (et.getId()) {
        case R.id.etUsername: {

        }
        break;

        case R.id.etPassword: {
            phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
            Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
            autochange=true;
            mPassword.setText(phone); 
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your TextWatcher, when you use setText it also invokes a callback on your TextWatcher so as soon as the user types something the TextWatcher goes in an endless loop where he constantly sets the text.

To prevent this the simplest although not best solution for all cases would be to use a flag to determine where that text changed callback is coming from. Try something like this:

```
private boolean isUserCallback = true;

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onTextChanged() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (s.length() != 0 && isUserCallback) {
        switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.etUsername: {

            }
            break;

            case R.id.etPassword: {
                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
                mPassword.setText(phone);  //THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            }
        }
    } else {
        isUserCallback = true;
    }
}
```

Only when isUserCallback is true you react to the callback. If you set the text programatically you just have to set the boolean to false:

```
this.isUserCallback = false;
mPassword.setText("asdf");
```

The isUserCallback flag will reset itself automatically in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue recently. Sometimes `setText` does not work with integers, you need to `setText(phone+"")`. This will work.

Comment: I actually found this on another stackoverflow post.  I already tried this.  It didn't fix my issue.

Comment: When you try setting an integer as the content of a EditText, this integer are being interpreted as a String Resource id. So if there isn't a String with this id, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the watcher before setting the text, and resetting the same watcher after.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onTextChanged() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (s.length() != 0) {
        switch (et.getId()) {
        case R.id.etUsername: {

        }
        break;

        case R.id.etPassword: {
            mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(theWatcher);
            phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
            Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
            mPassword.setText(phone);  //THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            mPassword.addTextChangedListener(theWatcher); 
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After see your -rejected by community- edit of my answer, I see the problem. When you invoke mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword)), you're trying to remove a new instance of TextWatcher, not the registered instance. Maybe in your case you can use mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(this) (same adding the watcher after setting the text).